# Debug-Execution Adventure

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, execution

I debugged my java code. It didn't give any errors.But when i executed it (it isn't giving errors either, but) the code didn't successfully terminate. This is very funny. But is that even possible?

Comment: This is typically due to side-effects in the `toString` methods.

Comment: I haven't used any tostring() method in my code

Comment: This is possible if the code is syntactically correct. From the standpoint of the JVM everything is fine although your logic may be incorrect. It is apparently executing the code correctly, although since the logic is flawed, it's not doing what you expected... if you could show your code that would be much better.

Comment: alright i'll put up my code in a while..but it involves a lot of exception handling..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, when the slowdown introduced by debugger does mask some race condition, but this normally  only applies to multi-threading or networking code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible that code works when debugging and doesn't work when running.  Two possible reasons I can think of right now are

- Concurrency in case of multithreading: if your debugger stops on a breakpoint, timing between multiple threads can change which can influence the behaviour
- When debugging, you can trigger certain parts of the code multiple times (more than when it has been executed without debugging), like for example via the toString method or via doing inspects or having some watch expression configured

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code can be syntactically correct (and thus might run without any errors) but may be semantically incorrect.

Assume the following:

```
public int add( int operand1, int operand2)
{
   return operant1 - operand2;
}
```

This would run without errors but still be incorrect due to logic/implementation error.

So, it IS possible to get wrong results by otherwise smoothly running code.

Comment: but isn't the main intention of debugging to find out even logical errors to understand the flow of execution too?

Comment: Yes, you debug to find logical errors but your success depends on how you debug and follow the program flow. Yet, as already stated by the others, if you have multiple processes running concurrently (which seems to be the case according to your code), debugging might mask racing conditions because it slows down or even halts execution of threads.