# Execution Problem

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, execution

I have debugged my java code.It doesn't seem to have any syntactical or LOGICAL errors. But when i execute the code, it is not terminating and not throwing any errors either. Can anybody please help me out with another way to deal with this?

This is my shell script -

```
echo "Name"
read name
if [ "$name" == "abcd" ]; then
 echo "correct name"
else
 echo "wrong name"
fi

echo "Password"
read password
if [ "$password" == "pwd" ]; then
 echo "Correct password"
else
 echo "Wrong password"
fi

echo "City"
read city
if [ "$city" == "bangalore" ]; then
 echo "correct city"
else
 echo "wrong city"
fi
```

---

This is my java code -

```
package Pack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import expectj.ExpectJ;
import expectj.Spawn;

public class Presentation extends Thread {

    public static StringBuffer execute(String cmd, List<Question> questions) {

        Utility u = new Utility();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        ExpectJ exp = new ExpectJ();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String answer = null;
        cmd = "sh /root/Desktop/details.sh";
        try {
            Spawn s = exp.spawn(cmd);
            Question q = null;
            int i = 0;
            while (i <= questions.size()) {
                System.out.println("iteration " + i);
                q = questions.get(i);
                try {
                    if (s.getCurrentStandardOutContents().contains(
                            q.getQuestion())) {
                        i++;
                    }
                    s.expect(q.getQuestion(), q.timeoutInSec);
                    if (q.isInteractive) {
                        System.out.println("Please provide your input: ");
                        answer = br.readLine();
                    } else {
                        if (q.isAnswerEncrypted) {
                            // TODO: decrypt the answer
                        } else {
                            answer = q.getAnswer();
                        }
                    }
                    s.send(answer + "\n");
                    i++;
                    try {
                        s.expectClose(3);
                        System.out.println("Script completed");
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Timeout!!!Please answer "
                            + s.getCurrentStandardOutContents());
                    try {
                        answer = u.PromptUserForAnswerInCaseOfException();
                        s.send(answer + "\n");
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.out.println("IO Exception..");
                    }
                }
            }
            s.expectClose();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("No more communication due to the lack of data");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return sb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String cmd = "sh /root/Desktop/details.sh";
        List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

        Question question1 = new Question();
        question1.setQuestion("Name");
        question1.setIsInteractive(false);
        question1.setAnswer("abcd");
        question1.setIsAnswerEncrypted(false);

        Question question2 = new Question();
        question2.setQuestion("Password");
        question2.setIsInteractive(true);
        question2.timeoutInSec = 5;
        question2.setAnswer("pwd");
        question2.setIsAnswerEncrypted(false);

        Question question3 = new Question();
        question3.setQuestion("City");
        question3.setIsInteractive(false);
        question3.timeoutInSec = 5;
        question3.setAnswer("bangalore");
        question3.setIsAnswerEncrypted(false);

        questions.add(question2);
        questions.add(question1);
        questions.add(question3);

        System.out.println(questions.toString());
        try {
            execute(cmd, questions);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any code, we can't help you. We do not have any psychic powers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug-Execution Adventure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910926/debug-execution-adventure)

Comment: Given that you've got an empty `catch(Exception e) {}` block, how are you ascertaining that no exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: At that particular position,if an exception is thrown,then (according to the code) nothing should happen (as nothing is given in the catch block). That is when the loop begins again, because if there is no exception thrown, then the execution will end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Regarding your program:

`while (i <= questions.size())` rings alarm bells. When variable `i` is equal to `questions.size()` you have already hit the end of the list. `questions.get(i)` will throw an exception because you are trying to read outside of the list. The clause should read `while (i < questions.size()`.

Original message: This is advice on how to debug a program that appears to be 'stuck in a loop':

If you are running in an IDE like Eclipse you can 'suspend' the program you are currently debugging. Then by looking at the call stack you can see where the execution point is currently. If it is in a system method you can 'setup return' until the execution point reaches your code.

Comment: I understand that..Its working just fine when debugging the code - It isn't highlighting any problem at all. But during runtime the while loop isn't working for the 3rd time, though the condition is satisfied.

Comment: In my case, does it matter? Because, out of the 3 iterations i have,the first 2 iterations will be having i=0(according to my logic, that is how its supposed to behave). During the 3rd iteration my i value will get incremented.

Answer (score 1):

If an exception occur within your loop it will never end, as you have no `break`. Maybe you could use a for loop instead.

Comment: Will it not end even if I am handling it properly? Because the debugger says I am handling it properly.

Comment: I don't know what "debugger says I am handling it properly" means. But as Jim already told you, variable 'i' won't be increased if an error occurs. And so you will retry that question forever.

Comment: Yes, there are no compile errors and according to me there are no logical errors either.